# Como manejar datos de formularios en Laravel

Tags: laravel

soy nuevo utilizando Laravel y necesito ayuda para entender mejor y de manera sencilla como manejar datos desde formularios en Laravel, para por ejemplo cargar, modificar, consultar y editar datos mediante métodos GET y POST, si tuviesen algún ejemplo sencillo de proyecto en Laravel se los agradecería ya que en lo que me pierdo es en el circuito de "ruta -> controlador (consulta de datos a la base de datos) -> vista" y luego que desde la "vista" debo a repetir el circuito.

Comment: aquí tienes un ejemplo https://platzi.com/blog/crud-laravel/

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask], para mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad incrementando las chances de obtener respuestas útiles.